# ReactiveCommand not updating UI

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui, avaloniaui

Reactive UI C# IObservable not acting as it should

Windows app, Avalonia UI (using mvvm).I created a register form with some textboxes and a register button.To that register button, i bound a reactive command,with the according parameters : execute and can execute.

Here :

[image: xaml for the button]

[image: binding in the viewmodel]

I have many fields in the register form, but for the sake of simplicity I will refer just to the FirstName field.I want the button to enable when the field is not empty and disable when it is.Since it is my first time using reactive UI, I read this :

https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/concepts/reactiveui/reactive-command

The problem is, my register button remains disabled even when I type something in the field, instead of updating.The problem may be at the other bindings, so here is how my User script looks like:

[image: user .cs]

[image: binding to FirstName in xaml]

The DataContext of registerview is the register viewmodel.
Here you can see it not working:

[image: registerview]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should never ever post code (which is plain text) as image, post it as text and mark it as code with the code tags

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `FirstName` setter and see if hits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you implemented the IReactiveObject interface wrong.

I tried your code with only that exception that I used RectiveObject on the User class which is not the perfect solution I know but it shows that there is the problem.

My code looks like this:

axaml:

```
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding User}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Watermark="First Name" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
  </Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        User = new User();
    }
}
```

User "model":

```
public class User : ReactiveObject
{
    private string? firstName = "John Doe";

    public string? FirstName
    {
        get => firstName;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref firstName, value);
    }

}
```

Well I'm not 100% sure but on models you should use INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Maybe check out [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) it helps with the boilerplate code.